# Paytabs iOS SDK zip integration

Tags: ios

i search for paytabs sdk integration but there is no found result 
 Any one can suggest me where can I get Paytabs iOS SDK zip file?!

Comment: Please send your request email at support@paytabs.com or customercare@paytabs.com.

Comment: If you have any integration queries, feel free to schedule a team viewer session with the support team.

Comment: they didn't answer , btw thanks

Comment: They will reply soon, you are welcome.

Comment: You can get it here, https://dev.paytabs.com/docs-apis/#ios-sdk

Answer (score 1):

You can download a demo from the following links

**For Objective C**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/40jjk40dmnfz79j/PayTabs_Objective%20c.zip?dl=0

**For Swift**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8sozqqgq8f2lx69/PayTabs_Swift.zip?dl=0

Comment: There is come issues that is 

:
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PayTabCardReaderViewController